How do I used if else in jsx?
How do I used if else in jsx?
I know I can do it like this
<h2 className='font-bold text-lx'>$ {item?.price == null && item?.type =='Sell' ? 'Please contact agency' :  (item.price) }</h2>
Because when the item?.price == null && item?.type =='Sell' I will show item.price
But if the item?.type =='Rent' I need to show item.rentMoney
So how could I modify it?
if the item?.price == null && item?.type =='Sell' show item.price and
the item?.type =='Rent' show item.rentMoney

Why show item.price if it's NULL ?

It's been a while since I last wrote in React.js but I think you can fulfill this requirement by using a ternary operator INSIDE a ternary operator:
<h2 className='font-bold text-lx'>
  {item?.price == null && item?.type === 'Sell' ? 'Please contact agency' : 
    (item?.type === 'Rent' ? item?.rentMoney : item?.price)}
</h2>

If you want to make it without ternaries you can also achieve it like so:
<h2 className='font-bold text-lx'>
  {(() => {
    if (item?.price == null && item?.type === 'Sell') {
      return 'Please contact agency';
    } else if (item?.type === 'Rent') {
      return item?.rentMoney;
    } else {
      return item?.price;
    }
  })()}
</h2>

you practically cut the jsx code short and insert whatever javascript code you need inside the {}

  
  {item?.price == null && item?.type === 'Sell'
    ? 'Please contact agency'
    : item.price !== null && item.price !== undefined
    ? `$ ${item.price}`
    : null}

